# Php - displaying date just one time

Tags: php

i try to solve a problem. i have an index page and users enter start and end date than press send a  list is come like that:

What i want is  to show date like that

```
  30191592 Izlesene.com izlesene_kanal_v4_360   1   
    30191592 Izlesene.com   izlesene_player_v4_240  1   
    30191592 Izlesene.com   player_mydonose 4   
    30191592 Izlesene.com   izlesene_sponsor_v4_360 16  
    30191592 Izlesene.com   izlesene_player_v4_360  32
    30191592 Izlesene.com   izlesene_cihan_v4   152
    30191592 Izlesene.com   izlesene_vodafone_v3    1052
    30191592 Izlesene.com   izlesene_sponsor_v4 3099    
    30191592 Izlesene.com   izlesene_kanal_v4   13727   
    30191592 Izlesene.com   izlesene_player_v4  2144704
    47335159 İzlesene Ntv   izlesene_player_v4  2546    
    47335159 Cihanhaber izlesene_cihan_v4   8794    2012-02-21
    30191592 Izlesene.com   izlesene_sponsor_v4 3099    
    30191592 Izlesene.com   izlesene_kanal_v4   13727
    30191592 Izlesene.com   izlesene_player_v4  2144704 
    47335159 İzlesene Ntv   izlesene_player_v4  2546    
    47335529 İzlesene Cihanhaber    izlesene_player_v4  2279    
    47335529 İzlesene Cihanhaber    izlesene_cihan_v4   8794    2012-02-20
```

I mean that i wanna show date just one time.

```
while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($dbResult)) {
                                        $total+= $info['totalEvents'];
                                        echo "<tr>";
                                        echo "<td><input type=checkbox name='check1' id='check1' value='" . $info['eventCategory'] . "' onclick=recal(" . $info['totalEvents'] . ",this.checked) checked></td><td>" . $info['id'] . "      " . $info['name'] . "</td>";
                                        echo "<td>" . $info['eventCategory'] . "</td>";
                                        echo "<td><id='totalEvents'>". $info['totalEvents'] . "</td>";
                                           echo "<td>". $info['Date'] . "</td>";
                                    }



                                    echo "<td><b id='total'>" . $total . "</b></td>";
```

This is my code what can be the changes?

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just check if the date is the same as the previous. You can do like this:

```
$previousDate = '';
while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($dbResult)) {
                                        $total+= $info['totalEvents'];
                                        echo "<tr>";
                                        echo "<td><input type=checkbox name='check1' id='check1' value='" . $info['eventCategory'] . "' onclick=recal(" . $info['totalEvents'] . ",this.checked) checked></td><td>" . $info['id'] . "      " . $info['name'] . "</td>";
                                        echo "<td>" . $info['eventCategory'] . "</td>";
                                        echo "<td><id='totalEvents'>". $info['totalEvents'] . "</td>";
                                        if ($info['Date'] != $previousDate){
                                           echo "<td>". $info['Date'] . "</td>";
                                        } else {
                                           echo "<td></td>";
                                        }
                                        $previousDate = $info['Date'];
                                    }



                                    echo "<td><b id='total'>" . $total . "</b></td>";
```

Answer (score 1):

So if I understand this right, then you would like to show every date only once. So how about saving date in some buffer variable and checking if the next date is the same. Something like this.

```
$buff = "";

while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($dbResult)) {
  $total+= $info['totalEvents'];
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td><input type=checkbox name='check1' id='check1' value='" . $info['eventCategory'] . "' onclick=recal(" . $info['totalEvents'] . ",this.checked) checked></td><td>" . $info['id'] . "      " . $info['name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $info['eventCategory'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td><id='totalEvents'>". $info['totalEvents'] . "</td>";
  if ($info['Date'] != $buff)
  {                                           
    echo "<td>". $info['Date'] . "</td>";
    $buff = $info['Date'];
  }
  else
  {                                           
    echo "<td></td>";
  }
}
echo "<td><b id='total'>" . $total . "</b></td>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a few trick can complete your requirement.

add in your query : `order by "date field name"`.

and then replace your while code as :

```
$tempDate;
while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($dbResult)) {
        if($tempDate == $info['totalEvents']) {
           //do that you want like merge the data of same date.
        } else {
          $tempDate = $info['totalEvents'];
          // create new row.
        }

     }
```

I think you can under this trick.